# django1.11 Custom authentication backend problem --return a unknown URL begin with /user/xxx?

Tags: django

I try to use the custom Authentication Backend in Django 1.11 to build the function (log-in with the user's email rather than the regular log-in with username. And both username and useremail are saved in the same user object in database).

With the following code, I can successfully login with username(I input correct username value in HTML form's username blank) and password as a pair. But in turn while I use the email value from HTML form input, It popups the Error as below in the background debug window:

> error "Not Found: /user/login/ ;
>   "POST /user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 404 "

I am very curious because there is never "user/login" at all in my whole urls.py and users.views.py. how does it come from?

Before this inquiry for help, I look up in Django official doc(version 1.11) and other suggestive comments in our stack overflow, but it still has no proper answer with this.

Hope your guys save me out and give your ideas.

Btw, I also check on 1.11 Django Docs, it said that 
"

```
Do not forget to test for the is_active attribute of the user in your own backend permission methods.

Changed in Django 1.10:
In older versions, the ModelBackend allowed inactive users to authenticate.
```

So I ever tried to solve this error according to the "is_acitve" check, but unfortunately, I don't' get it fixed yet.

-- Update: in MySQL db, I notice the current user object have fields

```
(is_staff =1; is_active=1)
```

but I don't get how to use the info to solve my current problem.

I run it out in Pycharm IDE, Django1.11, py 3.6, mysql5.7 (as DB to save the user table)

### --Important Update

: originally my testing browser is google chrome, after adopting the following Ruddra's correcting suggestion, new code can solve the issue successfully in browsers ( MS edge and firefox), but still not in google chrome. So now I prefer to classify this issue to "

#### Django 1.11 custom authentication backends have a conflict with chrome browser"

in setting.py,

```
    

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'users',
        'courses',
        'organization',
        'operation',
        'xadmin',
        'crispy_forms',
        'DjangoUeditor',
    ]

    AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.UserProfile"

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

in urls.py,

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    import xadmin
    from .settings import MEDIA_ROOT 
    from django.views.static import serve 
    from users. views import user_login

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^xadmin/', xadmin.site.urls),
        url(r'^media/(?P.*)$', serve, {"document_root": MEDIA_ROOT}), 
        url('^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
        url('^login/$', user_login, name='login'),
    name='upload'),
    ]
```

in users.views.py,

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
    from django.db.models import Q

    from .models import UserProfile

    class CustomBackend(ModelBackend):
        def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
            try:
                user = UserProfile.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(email=username))
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist as e:
                return None


    def user_login(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_name = request.POST.get("username", "")
            pass_word = request.POST.get("password", "")
            user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, "index.html")
            else:
                return render(request, "login.html", {"msg": "name or password erro！"})
        elif request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, "login.html", {})
```

in login.html,

[

```html
form action="/login/" method="post" id="jsLoginForm" autocomplete="off">
 input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='mymQDzHWl2REXIfPMg2mJaLqDfaS1sD5' />
 div class="form-group marb20">
  label>your name</label>
  input name="username" id="account_l" type="text" placeholder="手机号/邮箱" />
 /div>
 div class="form-group marb8">
  label>your password</label>
  input name="password" id="password_l" type="password" placeholder="please input your password" />
 /div>
 div class="error btns login-form-tips" id="jsLoginTips">{{ msg }}</div>
  div class="auto-box marb38">
  label><input type="checkbox" id="jsAutoLogin"> instant login </label>
  a class="fr" href="forgetpwd.html">forget your password？</a>
  /div>
  input class="btn btn-green" id="jsLoginBtn" type="submit" value="instant login > " />
 {% csrf_token %}
/form>
```

]

In the ideal situation,  after I input the correct user's email value and password value in HTML form, pressing 'login" button as well, then I assume to see I can log in to the index.html as I log in with the same user's name and user password as a pair to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what might go wrong here, I am guessing, one of your view is protected by a [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin), that might be configured with `user/login` route.

Also one thing you are missing is that, to add CustomBackend to your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'your_app.views.CustomBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
    )
```

Also in the view, rather than rendering the `index.html` when the login successful, redirect to the home page:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_name = request.POST.get("username", "")
        pass_word = request.POST.get("password", "")
        user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=pass_word)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {"msg": "name or password erro！"})
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "login.html", {})
```

Also, update the `login_html` like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" id="jsLoginForm" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Hi Rudra,  Thanks for your great help and code as a reference. Now the problem is solved in halfway, which is I can use these code to successfully log-in with email+pwd under firefox browser and Microsoft Edge, but still failed with the same error above, only in google chrome, my original browser as well. 
Now I classify this issue to "Django 1.11 custom authentication backends have a conflict with chrome browser"!  As an attempt, I first clear all chrome auth and cookies, then run code to re-test, but It is no change for reporting the same error again.

Comment: Sorry, i  can't tell why the problem is persistent in some browsers. Maybe some sort of cookie sharing better those browsers. Can you try with incognito mode please?

Comment: you are great but keep humble, I am so glad to benefit from your help and insight. The temporarily unknown "conflict with chrome "doesn't impact me seriously, I will really keep it in mind and go head for many other explorations. After all, only if we keep these discussions like sparkles left here, hope me or others can finally discover the left unknown issue soon later.

Comment: In google chrome incognito mode, it still fails with the same code which worked well in other browsers( firefox and ms edge)